# efficiently creating a list of pointers to a character in a buffer using arm neon simd

Tags: rust, arm64, neon

I've been rewriting some performance sensitive parts of my code to aarch64 neon.  For some things, like population count, i've managed to get a 12x speed.  But for some algorithms i'm having trouble..

The high level problem is quickly adding a list of newline separated strings to a hashset.  Assuming the hashset functionality is optimal (I am looking into it next), first i need to scan for the strings in the buffer.

I have tried various techniques - but my intuition tells me that I can create a list of pointers to each newline, and then insert them into the hashset afterwards now that i have the slices.

The fundamental problem is I can't work out an efficient way to load a vector, compare against the newline, and spit out a list of pointers to the newlines. eg. the output is a variable length, depending on how many newlines were found in the input vector.

Here is my approach;

```rust
fn read_file7(mut buffer: Vec<u8>, needle: u8) -> Result<HashSet<Vec<u8>>, Error>
{
    let mut set = HashSet::new();
    let mut chunk_offset: usize = 0;

    let special_finder_big = [
        0x80u8, 0x40u8, 0x20u8, 0x10u8, 0x08u8, 0x04u8, 0x02u8, 0x01u8, // high
        0x80u8, 0x40u8, 0x20u8, 0x10u8, 0x08u8, 0x04u8, 0x02u8, 0x01u8, // low
    ];

    let mut next_start: usize = 0;

    let needle_vector = unsafe { vdupq_n_u8(needle) };
    let special_finder_big = unsafe { vld1q_u8(special_finder_big.as_ptr()) };

    let mut line_counter = 0;
    // we process 16 chars at a time
    for chunk in buffer.chunks(16) {

        unsafe {
            let src = vld1q_u8(chunk.as_ptr());
            let out = vceqq_u8(src, needle_vector);
            let anded = vandq_u8(out, special_finder_big);
            // each of these is a bitset of each matching character
            let vadded = vaddv_u8(vget_low_u8(anded));
            let vadded2 = vaddv_u8(vget_high_u8(anded));

            let list = [vadded2, vadded];
            // combine bitsets into one big one!
            let mut num = std::mem::transmute::<[u8; 2], u16>(list);
            // while our bitset has bits left, find the set bits 
            while num > 0 {
                let mut xor = 0x8000u16; // only set the highest bit
                let clz = (num).leading_zeros() as usize;

                set.get_or_insert_owned(&buffer[(next_start)..(chunk_offset + clz)]);
                // println!("found '{}' at {} | clz is {} ", needle.escape_ascii(), start_offset + clz, clz);
                // println!("string is '{}'", input[(next_start)..(start_offset + clz)].escape_ascii());
                xor = xor >> clz; 
                num = num ^ xor;
                next_start = chunk_offset + clz + 1;
                //println!("new num         {:032b}", num);
                line_counter += 1;
            }
        }
        chunk_offset += 16;

    }

    // get the remaining 
    set.get_or_insert_owned(&buffer[(next_start)..]);

    println!(
        "line_counter: {} unique elements {}",
        line_counter,
        set.len()
    );

    Ok(set)
}
```

if I unroll this to do 64 bytes at a time, on a big input it will be slightly faster than memchr.  But not much.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably more fitting for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Stackoverflow is more targeted towards fixing specific errors that appear, performance optimization is more of a codereview thing.

Comment: This is great feedback, I didn't know about that site.  One thing it asks for is code that works correctly, but mine doesn't do what i'm asking for.  So it's kind of a grey area - eg. I have some code but it doesn't do what i'm asking, but i'm not even sure if that approach is correct.  I just had the code here to show my approach so far.

Comment: Ok I didn't realize you are struggling with the implementation, from skimming over it I had the impression that you have a working codebase that needs optimization through vectorization.

Answer (score 1):

I've shown this to a colleague who's come up with better intrinsics code than I would. Here's his suggestion, it's not been compiled, so there needs to be some finishing off of pseudo-code pieces etc, but something along the lines of below should be much faster & work:

```
let mut line_counter = 0;
for chunk in buffer.chunks(32) { // Read 32 bytes at a time
    unsafe {
        let src1 = vld1q_u8(chunk.as_ptr());
        let src2 = vld1q_u8(chunk.as_ptr() + 16);
        let out1 = vceqq_u8(src1, needle_vector);
        let out2 = vceqq_u8(src2, needle_vector);
        // We slot these next to each other in the same vector.
        // In this case the bottom 64-bits of the vector will tell you
        // if there are any needle values inside the first vector and
        // the top 64-bits tell you if you have any needle values in the
        // second vector.
        let combined = vpmaxq_u8(out1, out2);
        // Now we get another maxp which compresses this information into
        // a single 64-bit value, where the bottom 32-bits tell us about
        // src1 and the top 32-bit about src2.
        let combined = vpmaxq_u8(combined, combined);
        let remapped = vreinterpretq_u64_u8 (combined);
        let val = vgetq_lane_u64 (remapped, 0);
        if (val == 0) // most chunks won't have a new-line
          ... // If val is 0 that means no match was found in either vectors, adjust offset and continue.
        if (val & 0xFFFF)
          ... // there must be a match in src1. use below code in a function
        if (val & 0xFFFF0000)
          ... // there must be a match in src2. use below code in a function

    ...
    }
}
```

Now that we now which vector to look in, we should find the index in the vector
As an example, let's assume matchvec is the vector we found above (so either out1 or out2).

To find the first index:

```
// We create a mark of repeating 0xf00f chunks. when we fill an entire vector
// with it we get a pattern where every byte is 0xf0 or 0x0f. We'll use this 
// to find the index of the matches.
let mask = unsafe { vreinterpretq_u16_u8 (vdupq_n_u16 (0xf00f)); }

// We first clear the bits we don't want, which leaves for each adjacent 8-bit entries
// 4 bits of free space alternatingly.
let masked = vandq_u8 (matchvec, mask);
// Which means when we do a pairwise addition
// we are sure that no overflow will ever happen.  The entries slot next to each other
// and a non-zero bit indicates the start of the first element.
// We've also compressed the values into the lower 64-bits again.
let compressed = vpaddq_u8 (masked, masked);
let val = vgetq_lane_u64 (compressed, 0);
// Post now contains the index of the first element, every 4 bit is a new entry
// This assumes Rust has kept val on the SIMD side. if it did not, then it's best to
// call vclz on the lower 64-bits of compressed and transfer the results. 
let pos = (val).leading_zeros() as usize;
// So just shift pos right by 2 to get the actual index.
let pos = pos >> 2;
```

pos will now contain the index of the first needle value.

If you were processing out2, remember to add 16 to the result.

To find all the indices we can run through the bitmask without using clz, we avoid the repeated register file transfers this way.

```
// set masked and compressed as above
let masked = vandq_u8 (matchvec, mask);
let compressed = vpaddq_u8 (masked, masked);
int idx = current_offset;
while (val)
{
  if (val & 0xf)
   {
     // entry found at idx.
   }
   idx++;
   val = val >> 4;
}
```

Comment: I'm unpicking this right now :)

Comment: hmmm it doesn't make sense to me.  let's say out1 is 00ff0000 00000000 and out2 is 000000ff 00000000.  The vpmaxq will turn it to 0f000000 000f0000.  But i don't get how doing it again is useful? aren't you losing information at that point? because 0 and F maxed will be F, and will mean it's either in byte 0 or 1?

Comment: The maxs shorten the check, but means we no longer have an exact position. We can then go back to out1 and out2 to find the exact character, by passing them into the second function.